# How to convert this milliseconds into time (hh:mm a)?

Tags: java, android

I have milliseconds like "1325085788"  i  want to convert it on hh:mm a . i know this but return me time  01:34 PM instead of  08:53 PM.Whats problem ?

My code is ::

```
String created_on = "1325085788";
        String pattern = "hh:mm a";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

        Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(created_on));

        String yourFormatedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        System.out.println("--------> " + yourFormatedDate);
```

**no timezone issue because it give me current time (in india) in iphone app**

Comment: Can you please post the code you have used to print 01:34 PM? That may help us in identifying the issue.

Comment: Where are you? That sounds like a time zone issue.

Comment: sounds like a timezone thingy

Comment: no timezone issue because it give me current time (in india) in iphone app

Comment: @azad see my question...

Comment: Are you sure that number is right? That is only like 15 days after the epch - did you intend to have three '0's at the end to make it today?

Comment: ya I am sure and its work fine in iphone app ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1325085788 isn't milliseconds. It's seconds. Your expectations are off by a few orders of magnitude, but it's giving you the correct time for the given milliseconds.

If you have seconds and want to go to a Date, then something like this:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;

String created_on = "1325085788";
long millis = MILLISECONDS.convert(Long.parseLong(created_on), SECONDS);
Date d = new Date(millis);
```

After that, your date formatting should do the rest of the work.

Comment: OK Than how to convert it in hh:mm AM/PM Formate?

Comment: In this case, MULTIPLY by 1000 after parsing the Long

Comment: Equivalently: `SECONDS.toMillis(Long.parseLong(createdOn))`